# How to pass a flow-scope variable from one view-state to other view-state in spring-webflow

Tags: viewstate, spring-webflow, flow-scope

This query is about passing a flow-scope variable from one view-state to other view-state in spring-webflow.

Below code is a flow.xml file.
1. I have 2 view states in this file('firstView', 'secondView').
2. Here start-state is a view-state 'firstView', and on start I am setting a variable 'customizeBean' in flowscope. 
3. In 'firstView' view-state a transition 'selectUsers' is defined, which calls another view-state 'secondView'.
4. I want to access flow-scope variable 'customizeBean' in second view state 'secondView', basically I want to access 'customizeBean' on 'twinPickers.xhtml' page.
5.Please let me know how can I pass 'customizeBean' from first view state to second view-state.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd"
    start-state="firstView" parent="reportStandard" >

    <on-start>
        <set name="flowScope.customizeBean" value="customizeBean" />
    </on-start>

    <view-state id="firstView" view="customizeReport.xhtml">
            <transition on="selectUsers" to="secondView" />     
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="secondView"
        view="/WEB-INF/twinPickers.xhtml">
        <on-entry>
            <evaluate expression="reportAction.createTwinPicker" />
        </on-entry>
    </view-state>

    <bean-import resource="customizeReport-bean.xml" />
</flow>
```

Comment: Presumably your `customizeReport-bean.xml` contains a bean with the name "customizeBean", correct?

Answer (score 2):

Objects stored in the flowScope are available to all views in the flow for the life of the flow. You shouldn't have to pass them from view-state to view-state. Is the object you are storing in the flowScope Serializable?

http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/ch04s04.html#el-variable-flowScope